# Accessing a method property inside another method in VUE JS

Tags: api, methods, vue.js

How can I access a property from a method inside another method in VUEJS?
In this example, I need an "mb_id" from fetchMA method in order to use it in fetchMB args.

```
export default {
      name: 'details',
      data () {
         return {
            mA: {},
            mB: ''
         }
      },
      methods: {
         fetchMA(id){
            this.$http.get('apiurl/' + id )
            .then(function(response){
               this.mA = response.body;
            });
         },
         fetchMB(id){
            this.$http.get('apiurl/' + id )
            .then(function(response){
               this.mB = response.body;
            });
         }
      },
      created: function(){
         this.fetchMA(this.$route.params.id);
         this.fetchMB(this.mA.mb_id);
      }
   }
```

If I hard code a digit inside the created, such as - this.fetchMB(10); this fetches what I need, but for obvious reasons this is not feasible.

Thank you all,

-S

Comment: Is `mA` an array or an object that has an `mb_id` property?

Comment: @Bert an object, just a typo. fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning the promise from `fetchMA()` will allow you to call `then()` on it so you can wait until `this.mA` has been set.

```
fetchMA(id){
    return this.$http.get('apiurl/' + id )
    .then(function(response){
        this.mA = response.body;
    });
},
```

You can then use it like this in `created`:

```
this.fetchMA(id)
.then(() => {
    this.fetchMB(this.mA.mb_id);    
})
```

It's not really clear what `this.mA` is from your example. You are declaring it like an array, but accessing it like an object.

Comment: Perfect, worked. I missed the return call inside the fetchMA method. Thank you so much!